# Why is this unpacking expression not allowed in python3.10?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

I used to unpack a long iterable expression like this:

In python 3.8.7:

```py
>>> _, a, (*_), c = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a
2
>>> c
6
```

In python 3.10.7:

```py
>>> _, a, (*_), c = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    _, a, (*_), c = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
           ^^
SyntaxError: cannot use starred expression here
```

I'm not sure which version of python between 3.8.7 and 3.10.7 introduced this backwards breaking behavior. What's the justification for this?

Comment: Not an answer but removing the parenthesis works `_, a, *_, c = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: @IainShelvington +1'd the fix. There are hundreds of places where I(and others) do this unpacking in a large codebase, so a small amount of refactoring effort would be needed which is annoying. I wonder if there's a theoretical justification for this?

Comment: The syntax with parentheses works in 3.9 so it must be a change introduced in 3.10

Comment: @IainShelvington actually I just tried with Python 3.9.13 and it just works without parentheses

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but under [language changes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#other-language-changes) for 3.10, it says _Assignment expressions can now be used unparenthesized within set literals and set comprehensions, as well as in sequence indexes (but not slices)._. I wonder if they meant to say that _unparenthesized_ is the only way to go, instead of making sound like parenthesized was still an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an official discussion [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue40631). The most relevant quote I can find is:

> > Also the current behavior allows `(*x), y = 1` assignment. If `(*x)` is to be totally disallowed, `(*x), y = 1` should also be rejected.

> I agree.

The final "I agree" is from Guido van Rossum.

The rationale for rejecting `(*x)` was:

> Honestly this seems like a bug in 3.8 to me (if it indeed behaves like
> this):
>
> ```
> >>> (*x), y (1, 2, 3)
> ```
>
> Every time I mistakenly tried (*x) I really meant (*x,), so it's
> surprising that (*x), y would be interpreted as (*x, y) rather than
> flagging (*x) as an error.
>
> Please don't "fix" this even if it is a regression.

Also by Guido van Rossum. So it seems like `(*x)` was rejected because it looks too similar to unpacking into a singlet tuple.