# Updated Python Starred Expressions Error in Numpy Indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, syntax-error

I have some code that I have been running in Python 3.6, but when I move to Python 3.9 I recieve the below error:

```
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

I understand some syntax related to expressions of the form `(*something)` was implemented in 3.9 that is not backwards compatible (see, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73888639/why-is-this-unpacking-expression-not-allowed-in-python3-10)).

Here is a minimal working example of what my code tries to do:

```
# Get some data
y = np.random.randn(100,100,100)

# Indexes stored as a tuple
x = (1,2)

# Result I'm after
result = y[...,(*x)]
```

In the above example, I am trying to essentially return `y[:,1,2]`, but in practice, my tuple may have more values, and my array may be larger.

The above code works fine in Python 3.6 but doesn't work in Python 3.9. I cannot work out what the equivalent piece of code would be in Python 3.9 and above. I don't want to assume the number of dimensions in Y (e.g. I want to keep the `...`), but I want to retain the behaviour I have above. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `[...,(*x)]` ever worked.  `(*x,)` is a valid way of turning a list into a tuple.  And `fn(*x)` is ok.  But `(*x)` looks odd, in any version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
result = y[(..., *x)]
```

Intermediate:

```
(..., *x)
# (Ellipsis, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! You have no idea how long I spent and still missed this!